# add results to linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm querying a datatable using linq, I then query the results to filter out what I want, the problem is that I need to query it for each value of an array these values are like this ,2, or ,22, or ,21, etc

so I usually do this

```
results = from a in results
     where a.countryId.ToString().Contains(value)
     select a;
```

what I would like to do is this

```
foreach(string str in arrayval)
{
results += from a in results 
      where a.countryId.ToString().Contains(str)
}
```

can anyone help or give me some clues

thanks

Comment: You're not doing anything with your `str` value in your loop? What is the purpose of that loop?

Comment: Have you tried and got an error?
You aren't using `str` or `arrayval` in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to select results based on comparison from the array values. Something like. `Select * from table where ID in (1,2,3)`. Instead of concatenating results you can try the following query.

```
var result = from a in result
             where arrayval.Contains(a.CountryId.ToString())
             select a;
```

if your `arrayval` is an int type array then you may remove `.ToString()` at the end of `a.CountryID`

Comment: CountryId should contain value substring. In your case you just verify that CountryId equals to one of values. So, it changes original intent (I don't say that original intent was correct) :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, CountryID, should contain only a single ID. May be I am wrong, but thats what I understood from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
results.Where(a=> arrayval.Contains(a.CountryId.ToString()).Aggregate("", (a,b)=> a+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a list of your array values e.g.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "2",
    "12",
    "20",
    //etc...
};
```

and then do

```
var result = results.Where(p => list.Contains(p.countryId.ToString()));
```

Basically you are only select `countryId`'s that are contained in the list.